# UrlGenerationError when testing controller usinf Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, controller-tests

I am trying to run basic controller test.

My controller_spec.rb looks like:

```
class Test < ActionController::Base
  def test_meth
    puts 'hello for test meth'
    head 200
  end
end

describe Test do
  it 'responds with 200' do
    get :test_meth
    expect(response.status).to eq(200)
  end
end
```

When I run this spec I end up with an error

`ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"test_meth", :controller=>"test"}`

I am not sure if I am missing something very basic here becasue this looks very straight forward. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear, in your `routes.rb` file you have not written the action correctly.

You must have.

`get "test", to: "test#test_meth"`